# pymongo find_one does not work properly

Tags: python, pymongo-3.x

I have a collection named *terminals* in my mongodb database. This collection has documents with a field named *merchant* which it's values are partly string and partly integer. I cast all the values to string using this piece of code in python:

```
for i in terminals.find():
    if "merchant" in i.keys():
        terminals.update_one({"_id": i["_id"]}, {"$set": {"merchant": str(i["merchant"])}})
```

Then something strange happens when I try to query on the this collection.
this one works:

```
print(merchant_category.find_one({"merchant": 000000000194267}))
```

and this one doesn't:

```
print(merchant_category.find_one({"merchant": "000000000194267"}))
```

While querying with mongodb shell, the opposite happens; I mean it returns nothing when I use integer as the value since all the values are stored in string. Can anyone answer the question: **what is the problem with python and how can I fix it?**